# Basic limit calculation

Tags: limits

How would one calculate the following limit with basic pre calculus knowledge? I would like to see the process of dividing this expression with the highest power - $25^n$.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left({\frac{2^{2n+1}+3\cdot 5^{2n+1}}{2\cdot3^{2n-1}+25^{n}}}\right)$$

**EDIT**:

If this expression would have a $(-1)^{n}$ in it, what would the limit be.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left({\frac{2^{2n+1}+3\cdot 5^{2n+1}}{2\cdot3^{2n-1}+(-1)^{n}25^{n}}}\right)$$

Comment: Nice of you to come back, but do you have anything to say about the answer Matthias left here two days ago?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have

$\begin{align}
 \frac{2^{2n+1}+3 \cdot5^{2n +1}}{2 \cdot 3^{2n-1} + 25^n} 
&= \frac{2 \cdot2^{2n}+15 \cdot 5^{2n}}{\frac{2}{3} \cdot 3^{2n} + 5^{2n}} \\
&= \frac{2 \cdot (\frac{2}{5})^{2n}+15}{\frac{2}{3} \cdot (\frac{3}{5})^{2n} + 1}\\ 
\end{align}$

and so you get $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2^{2n+1}+3 \cdot5^{2n +1}}{2 \cdot 3^{2n-1} + 25^n} = 15$.

**Edit:**

This $(-1)^n$ makes your sequence divergent.
If you let $a_n = \frac{2^{2n+1}+3 \cdot5^{2n +1}}{2 \cdot 3^{2n-1} + (-1)^n 25^n} $ you can look at the subsequences $(a_{2n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(a_{2n +1 })_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$. A computation like the one above shows
$$ a_{2n} = \frac{2 \cdot (\frac{2}{5})^{4n}+15}{\frac{2}{3} \cdot (\frac{3}{5})^{4n} + 1}$$ converging to $15$
and $$ a_{2n+1} = \frac{2 \cdot (\frac{2}{5})^{4n+2}+15}{\frac{2}{3} \cdot (\frac{3}{5})^{4n+2} - 1}$$ converging to $-15$.

Comment: Matt (not Matthias!), would you care to accept this answer, or were you looking for something different?